# Unable to figure out why react app is not showing the result in the webpage from the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs

I am trying to build a sorting visualiser using react and when i created a random array and i tried to display the numbers on the web page .It's not showing anything on page and all the directory paths are correct.
My app.js file is here `

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import checking from './components/chekcing';
import SortingVisualizer from './SortingVisualizer/SortingVisualizer';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <SortingVisualizer></SortingVisualizer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`
and SortingVisualizer.jsx file is here

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import './SortingVisualizer.css'

 export class SortingVisualizer extends Component {
     //normal constructor to intialise the array
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
        array:[],
         }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.resetArray();
    }
    // to reset the array or to generate the new array
    resetArray(){
        const array=[];
          for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
               array.push(randomIntFromInterval(5,1000));
        }
        this.setState(array);
    }
    render() {
        const {array}=this.state;
        return (
            <>
            {
            array.map((value, idx) =>{
                 
                 return <div className="array-bar" key={idx} >{value}</div>
             
              })}
            </>
        );
    }
          
    }

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max){
return Math.floor(Math.random*(max-min+1)+min);
}
export default SortingVisualizer
```

i included the return inside the array map function because arrow functions would expect the explicit return statement

Comment: React state keeps key-value objects, so change `this.setState(array)` to `this.setState({array: array})`

Comment: thank you !,but still it's not printing the numbers on page . it's values are initialised to `NaN` and they are not getting updated with the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually invoke `Math.random()` inside your `randomIntFromInterval()` function, so change it to return `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);`